# Can a very strong force hold three massless particles, with charges associated to this force, together?

Tags: particle-physics

Consider three massless (unspecified), spin $\frac 1 2$ elementary particles. They possess charges comparable to the colour charges of the colour force in QCD (which keeps quarks together). The difference being that the force is much bigger than the one in QCD. Can this force prevent the particles from flying apart?

Comment: I don't understand the logic of this question. The color force, which is strong, keeps quarks together in a proton; and you ask if an even stronger force would also keep them together?

Comment: You seem to be asking for a [glueball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glueball).

Comment: @ACuriousMind-Glueballs consist of massless vector bosons (gluons), which are held together by the same particles (again the vector gluons associated with the colour force), which is a slightly different question. They can exist briefly, but not as stable particles.;-)

Comment: @MitchellPorter-I'm not asking this question in the context of quarks (which have mass) but in the context of massless fermions (as explicitly stated in my question), which are held together by a very strong force (which is obviously much stronger than the colour force). :-)

Comment: It seems that the quarks in a proton have a small mass coming from Higgs ("current mass") and then a much larger additional mass coming from QCD effects ("constituent mass"). If there was no current mass, you'd still have protons...

Comment: But let's get much simpler. Suppose you had a string rotating so its endpoints move at the speed of light. The endpoints of the string are the particles and the tension in the string is the attractive force. Is this scenario relevant to your question?